# PHP __LINE__ equivalent for twig

Tags: twig

There is a way to get PHP `__LINE__` equivalent for `Twig`?

It's almost impossible to search `__LINE__` on Google as exact word...

The purpose is purely for debugging a long twig file containing nested twig code inside a complex Js code, to `console.log` it.

The version of twig I'm using is `2.12.5`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First things first:

As seen in the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php) the (magic) constant will return the current line number of the file.
The "problem" here is that `twig` converts templates to `PHP` in order to render them.

This means if you were actually were to be able to use `__LINE__` inside a template, it would report back the line number from either a temporary PHP file or a cached PHP file, wether you have caching enabled or not.

**TLDR**: Using `__LINE__` inside a template is going to report back "false"/useless information.

---

However, you can easily extend `twig` and even introduce new tags which you then can use inside templates. These customs tags allow you to modify/alter the compilation of the template's `PHP` file.

The interesting part here is that the "compiler" is able to provide your custom tag on which specific line the tag was called.

We can even create a custom tag, register it with `twig` and let the tag report back the line number in the parsed template.

**Step 1** - Create a TokenParser

The `TokenParser` is responsible for parsing the template and allows you to choose a name for your tag. The code below will be responsible to create a simple, empty tag named `line`

```
<?php
    namespace MyProject\Base\Twig\TokenParser;

    use \MyProject\Base\Twig\Node\Line as LineNode;

    class Line extends \Twig_TokenParser {

        public function parse(\Twig_Token $token)
        {
            $this->parser->getStream()->expect(\Twig_Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE);
            return new LineNode(new \Twig_Node(), $token->getLine(), $this->getTag());
        }

        public function getTag()
        {
            return 'line';
        }
}
```

**Step 2** - Create a Node

The `Node` is responsible for converting the template code to actual `PHP` code

```
<?php
    namespace MyProject\Base\Twig\Node;

    class Line extends \Twig_Node {
        public function __construct(\Twig_NodeInterface $body, $lineno, $tag = null) {
            parent::__construct(['body' => $body,], array(), $lineno, $tag);
        }

        public function compile(\Twig_Compiler $compiler) {
            $compiler->write('echo '.$this->getLine().';')
                     ->write(PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
```

**Step 3** - Register the tag with `twig`

```
<?php
    namespace MyProject\Base\Twig;

    class MyProjectTwigExtension extends Twig_Extension {
        public function getTokenParsers() {
            return [
                new \CMS4U\Base\Twig\TokenParser\Line(),
            ];
        }

        public function getName() {
            return 'MyProjectTwigExtension';
        }
    }
```

```
<?php
    $twig->addExtension(new \MyProject\Base\Twig\MyProjectTwigExtension());
```

---

If everything is good, you can now use the custom tag `{% line %}` wherever you like in any template

```
Foo
Bar
FooBar
Current line number is {% line %} {# 4 #}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was looking for something more simple, I cannot do that on my work project.

Comment: (why do you still edit the question's title removing `for twig`?? With this all users can easily more understand the topic)

Comment: @user2342558 Didn't you read the first part of my answer? There is no simple way to solve this